# how to click an icon in webpage with keyboard shortcut?

Tags: html, keyboard, click, icons, shortcut

is it possible to create a shortcut keys like ctrl + A will click on the Add button and ctrl + B will be for submitting and ctrl + E for new Entity ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using JS-

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
if (event.altKey && event.code === "X")
    {
        //what function you want to execute do here
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```